# Generating BOM with hierarchial query

Tags: sql, sql-server, recursion, hierarchy, sql-server-2012

I have Microsoft SQL Server 2012 and there is table that contains all information about BOM's (bill of materials). Data is in this format:

```
Item   | SubItem  | Quantity
item_1 | item_2   | 2
item_1 | item_3   | 3
item_1 | item_4   | 2
item_2 | item_5   | 2
item_2 | item_6   | 2
```

and so on...

So if i want to have 10 pieces of item_1, then it have to multiply all item's and items sub items  quantities with this multiplier. And i would like to achieve this kind of result with query:

```
item_1 - 10pcs - 1 lvl
  item_2 - 20pcs - 2 lvl
    item_5 - 40pcs - 3 lvl
    item_6 - 40pcs - 3 lvl 
  item_3 - 30pcs - 2 lvl
  item_4 - 20pcs - 2 lvl
```

Any tips how this could be achieved in a good way?  If this isn't possible to do with queries, then my other option is to do all tricks in Excel's VBA.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with a recursive query.  Here is something to get you started:

```
with all_item_counts as (
select item, subitem, quantity as q, 0 as level from bom
union all 
select all_item_counts.item, bom.subitem, quantity * q, level + 1 
    from all_item_counts
    join bom on bom.item = all_item_counts.subitem
)
select item,subitem,sum(q) from all_item_counts
   group by item, subitem
   order by item, subitem
```

The result of query is the total number of each `subItem` needed to make a particular `item`.

You can see it working in [an SQLFiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/0738b/1).  I added a bit to your sample data to show that a more complicated case works.